# Is it possible to release a library based on the ASIO SDK under the LGPLv3?

Tags: open-source, licensing, lgpl

I'm wondering if it's possible to write and release a library based on the ASIO SDK under the LGPLv3.

More specifically, the [ASIO license](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/23181570/Steinberg-ASIO-License-Agreement) says something I'm not sure how to interpret (2.2) :

> The Licensee has no permission to [...]. This includes re-working this specification, **or reverse-engineering any products based upon this specification.**

Which sounds like it could conflict with LGPL's:

> You may convey a Combined Work under terms of your choice that, taken together, effectively do not restrict modification of the portions of the Library contained in the Combined Work and reverse engineering for debugging such modifications

Also, 5.a) is kind of bugging me :

> Accompany the combined library with a copy of the same work based on the Library, uncombined with any other library facilities

The way I see it, my Library will have no use, point or effect on its own, when uncombined with the ASIO SDK. Will I still have to release an uncombined dummy piece of software to respect 5.a) if I choose LGPL?

Comment: You should ask Steinberg if it is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can't provide copies of the ASIO SDK.

You could develop code which uses it but have your customers get the SDK from ASIO directly and then link with your code.

You may also be able to distribute parts of the SDK (typically binary libs/dlls) with your product without supplying the entire SDK - this would be typical for commercial apps.

The reverse engineering clause is standard boilerplate - interestingly since the company says GMBH they are presumably German and should know that this clause is illegal in the Eu.